# LINQ & Enumeration

Tags: c#, linq, enumeration

I have this enumeration

```
public enum LightFiles
    { 
        PNG,
        JPG,
        GIF,
        FLV,
        TIF,
        BMP,
        MP3,
        WAV,
        WMA,
        TXT,
        PDF,
        XML,
        DOC,
        XLS,
        DBF,
        SQL,
        CSS,
        HTM
    }
```

And I need to detect if the file name has one of the enum. item and return  TRUE if it is.

I guess there is some solution  via LINQ. I really don't klnow how to work around to resolve this problem...

Any clue guys?

```
static public bool IsLightFile(string fileName)
{ 
  // Needs some LINQ
}
```

Comment: Do you want it anywhere in the file name?  Or just the extension?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare  the extension only. Thank you for your detailed input @JamesMichaelHare! (+1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
static public bool IsLightFile(string fileName)
{
  //Use any with names returned from the enum.
   return Enum.GetNames(typeof(LightFiles)).Any(w => w == fileName);    
}
```

Comment: Actually, you could use `Enum.IsDefined()` to check and avoid the `Any()` altogether.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare , that is true, but with Any we can have control eg. you test mixed case Enum.IsDefind() will fail when you pass "dOC" but with .Any you can use .Any(w => w.ToLower() == fileName.ToLower())

Comment: @SurjitSamra: Very true, though you could do that with `Contains()` instead, using `ToLower()` to do string comparissons is costly, instead use `Contains()` with a `StringComparisson.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A little unsure precisely what you are asking, I can see three possibilities...

If you just want the file name to contain any of the enum strings, you could do:

```
    static public bool IsLightFile(string fileName)
    {
        foreach (var eVal in Enum.GetNames(typeof(LightFiles)))
        {
            if (fileName.Contains(eVal))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Or, if you want to see if it just ends with that extension, you could do:

```
    static public bool IsLightFile(string fileName)
    {
        foreach (var eVal in Enum.GetNames(typeof(LightFiles)))
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(fileName).Equals(eVal))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Or, if you are saying that the `filename` must be equal to the `enum` value completely, you can do:

```
    static public bool IsLightFile(string fileName)
    {
        return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LightFiles), fileName);
    }
```

Obviously, you'd want to null check, make string compare case-insensitive, etc as necessary.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I know. But I guess it should be some LINQ solution.

Comment: Why does it have to be a LINQ solution?  Were you told to do this with LINQ specifically?

Comment: @DmitryBoyko: Contains() is a LINQ extension method.  Or do you mean you must do it as a LINQ expression?  If so, why?

Comment: @James Michael Hare Well I don't try to LINQize everything but I am just wondering if it is possible to play around LINQ & Enumeration.

Comment: Dmitry, if someone had been trying to nail up pictures with a screwdriver, and someone gave them a hammer, should they say "But I guess it should be some screwdriver solution"?

Comment: @insta I asked: "I guess there is some solution via LINQ."

Comment: @DmitryBoyko: While there is a lot of possibilities to use the LINQ extension methods here, it doesn't really seem like it needs a full query.  So, this answer does utilize LINQ, just not the expression syntax.

Comment: @JonHanna  Yo! I don't ask for the BEST solution. I asked in general about the POSSIBLE solution. :)

Comment: @DmitryBoyko To add two numbers, do you write the function as `int f(int a, int b) { return (from t in new[] { a, b } select t).Sum(); }` ? It's possible, it's valid C#, but it's just stupid.

Comment: But there's never a case where you can perform Linq where you can't perform C#. It's not about best, it's a matter of vaguely sane.

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool IsLightFile(string filename)
{
    return Enum.GetNames(typeof(LightFiles)).Contains(
        Path.GetExtension(filename).Remove(0, 1).ToUpper());
}
```

The only way LINQ plays a part in this is the [Enumberable.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357185%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) extension method.

See also:

[Enum.GetNames()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/928552tz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
[Path.GetExtension()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zef1adzx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
[String.Remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/143t8z3d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
[String.ToUpper()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k541xwh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
static public bool IsLightFile(string fileName)
    {
      var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).Remove(0, 1);
      return Enum.GetNames(typeof(LightFiles)).Any(enumVal => string.Compare(enumVal, extension, true) == 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you'd use LINQ here. To see if a string is a valid enum value, a slightly more natural solution than looping over `Enum.GetNames`'s results, whether explicitly or implicitly using LINQ, would be `Enum.TryParse`.

```
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
if (fileExtension.StartsWith("."))
    fileExtension = fileExtension.Substring(1);
LightFiles lightFile;
return Enum.TryParse(fileExtension, true, out lightFile);
```

Note: the alternative `Enum.IsDefined` is always case sensitive, while file extensions are usually treated as case insensitive.